# What's the difference between '.Object' and 'object' in R S4 initialize function?

Tags: r, r-s4

I use S4 in R and what to define a *initialize* function. But *.Object* works well and *object* will failed. why?

```
############ method1: Bad
setMethod("initialize", "XY2Z", function(object,...){
  object <- callNextMethod()
  object@nodes <- getNodes(object)
  object
})
########### method2: Good
setMethod("initialize", "XY2Z", function(.Object,...){
  .Object <- callNextMethod()
  .Object@nodes <- getNodes(.Object)
  .Object
})
```

method1: Error in conformMethod(signature, mnames, fnames, f, fdef, definition) : 
  带'initialize'标记的'.Object="XY2Z"'的方法： 方法定义里所忽略的正式参数(.Object = "XY2Z", ... = "XY2Z")不能存在于标记

method2: work well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am uncertain about why the error arises just in one case, however here might be a fix

```
initialize <- function(object,...) 0
setGeneric("initialize")
# method 1 (doesn't give an error)
setMethod("initialize", "XY2Z", function(object,...){
  object <- callNextMethod()
  object@nodes <- getNodes(object)
  object
})
```

Comment: Thanks!!! setGeneric("initialize") is enough to fix this. It seems that the .Object is necessary without  setGeneric("initialize")